# Path to web directory and assets in .js files in symfony2

Tags: javascript, symfony, web, twig, assets

I'm googling and googling and can't find what I need.

How to get path to "web" directory in symfony2 in

- action [no idea, i only found solution for older versions of symfony:
  $sf_relative_url_root = sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest()->getRelativeUrlRoot();
  I've tried also $this->get('security.context')->getRequest()->getRelativeUrlRoot(), but it doesn't work]
- .js file

In case of .js file I do for now in twig template something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var asset_url="{{asset(' ')}}"; 
asset_url = asset_url.substr(0, asset_url.length-1);
</script>
<script href="{{asset('js/script.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

is a better way?

Comment: I don't get it, why do you need first javascript code? why not just use {{ asset('js/script.js') }} ? it should work just fine..

Comment: Are you sure this is a question on Symfony2?

Comment: First js code is written, because i can't use {{asset('smth')}} in .js file and i ask how to do that.

@elnur: in case of first point i think so.

Comment: For now I use in script.js variable asset_url to do things connected with path to web directory.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, then what you're looking for is `$this->getRequest()->getUri()` in a controller class.

Take a look at `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` class if it's not, you will most likely find it there.

Comment: almost, it returns:
http://localhost/project/main/app_dev.php/action/
I would like only 
http://localhost/project/main/
but it's easy to cut:)  
Second question left[js file] - is there better way?

Comment: Maybe `Request::getBasePath()` then? as for .js easiest way I can think of is to set base_url param in your parameters.ini, then you can access it at any point as twig variable. It will also work for controller

Comment: Thanks! Actually it should be $this->getRequest()->getBasePath().
In case of js file i can't use twig things in .js file, if i could i would use {{asset('smth')}}

Comment: To get full URL I do for example: $url = 'http://'.$this->getRequest()->headers->get('host').$this->getRequest()->getBasePath().'/scripts/script.php'